# Standardize the character format in a table

Tags: sql

There is a table in my PieCloudDB Database and some example data are as follows:

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | a Lice |
| 2 | b O B |
| 3 | michael |
| 4 | DAVID |
| 5 | S aM |
| 6 | emiL y |
| 7 | nANCy |

In the table, there are many names with formatting issues. Some names even contain whitespaces(at the beginning, middle, or end). I want to standardize all the names so that each name has only the first character capitalized and the rest in lowercase and remove all whitespaces. (In all the names, there will only be whitespaces and no other special characters.)

out:

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Alice |
| 2 | Bob |
| 3 | Michael |
| 4 | David |
| 5 | Sam |
| 6 | Emily |
| 7 | Nancy |

I know that the INITCAP function can quickly capitalize the first character of a string and convert the rest to lowercase, but I'm not sure how to handle whitespaces.

Comment: I don't use PieCloudDB, but the standard SQL function to remove spaces is `REPLACE`. So you can try `REPLACE(name,' ','')`. Or `INITCAP(REPLACE(name,' ',''))`

Answer (score 0):

You can try this query in your database. Using the REPLACE function to remove all spaces.

```
SELECT id ,INITCAP(replace(name,' ','')) AS formatted_name
FROM pieclouddb
ORDER BY id ASC;
```

Comment: Well, I will correct my answer.@JonasMetzler

Comment: Are you absolutely sure that the query will work in PieCloudDB? If you are, I think you should edit your answer and remove the "you can try" part. Otherwise, you can remove the answer because it would just be a duplicate of my comment below the question ;)